# Why is the respond_to js not being executing using jQuery AJAX in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm running a simple AJAX post to my server and the `respond_to` .js block is returned as a 200 success but is not executed.  Am I missing something in my configuration or in my code for the execution the return js code?  I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9.

javascript:

```
    $("#test-submit").on("click",function(event){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/users',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          "test" : "test-data"
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

controller action:

```
  def create
    user = User.find(current_user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { }
    end
  end
```

user create.js.erb:

```
alert('hai');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
...
dataType: 'json',
...
```

You expect JSON data, not executable script. Try to change this line to

```
dataType: 'script',
```